# Where is the cache stored in imageresizing.net when using DiskCache plugin and Azure blob storage?

Tags: imageresizer

If I have a setup with Azure blob storage (usiung AzureReader2 plugin), and I also use the DiskCache plugin, where is the cached image actually stored?

For example, I have an image as http://test.blob.core.windows.net/images/test.jpg, so the resized version is http://test.azurewebsites.net/azure/images/test.jpg?width=50. If I am also using the DiskCache plugin, is a cached version of this request created? And if so where, in the Azure space? If this is the case, I am concerned that this space (usually reserved for the Azure web site) will be geneally quite limited.

Unless the cached version is created in the blob storage itself, in which case everything is perfect

Answer (score 1):

I used FTP to access the Azure website, and there stands imagecache folder in all its glory.